# Create an external Hive table from an existing external table

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have a set of CSV files in a HDFS path and I created an external Hive table, let's say table_A, from these files. Since some of the entries are redundant, I tried creating another Hive table based on table_A, say table_B, which has distinct records. I was able to create table_B as a non-external table (Hive warehouse). I want to know if I can create table_B as an external table? If this is possible, will it copy the records from table_A and create its own table_B store on a specified path (preferably as CSV also)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am presuming you want to select distinct data from "uncleaned" table
>   and insert into "cleaned" table.
>
> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `uncleaned`(
>   `a` int, 
>   `b` string,
>   `c` string, 
>   `d` string, 
>   `e` bigint
>   ) 
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
>   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
> OUTPUTFORMAT 
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
> LOCATION
>   '/external/uncleaned'
> ```

create another table, it can be external or not(doesn't matter).

> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `cleaned`(
>   `a` int, 
>   `b` string,
>   `c` string, 
>   `d` string, 
>   `e` bigint
>   ) 
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
>   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
>   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
> OUTPUTFORMAT 
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
> LOCATION
>   '/external/cleaned'
> ```
>
> Read from first table and you can insert it by
>
> ```
> insert overwrite table cleaned 
>
> select distinct a,b,c,d,e from uncleaned;
> ```